# Run sudo command via ssh

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I'm trying to run command `sudo -u [USER] [COMMAND]` from java code on remote Linux machine and  nothing happened. I use the `ganymed-ssh2 jar`. When I run the command without sudo its work perfect.

Also if I run `sudo -u [USER] [COMMAND]` from Linux machine it works perfect. How I can run this command from java?

```
Connection conn= SshConnection.GetConnection(hostname, username, password)

Session sess= conn.openSession(); 

sess.execCommand(command);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you mention password while running comand with `sudo`? Or, your user is marked with NOPASSWD is sudoers file?

Comment: It works without password

Comment: Is there any output here?

Comment: You can only run this remotely if the `sudoers` configuration allows this specific command executed by the given user in the name of the other user to run w/o asking for password.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the secured stream and pass the password.

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' " + command);
channel.setInputStream(null);
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
channel.connect();
out.write((password + "\n").getBytes());
out.flush();;
```

Taken from here: http://codeflex.co/java-run-sudo-command-on-remote-linux-host/

Answer (score 1):

You can only run this remotely if the `sudoers` configuration on the server allows this specific command executed by the given user in the name of the other user to run w/o asking for password (i.e. `NOPASSWD` option). Password entry for `sudo` can only be keyboard interactive which you cannot do remotely.

Comment: The part about non interactive is not entirely true, it is entirely possible to use APIs that supplies the password remotely, if the API need to fake an interactive session so be it.